# Por que no funciona mi método invierteArreglo

Tags: java

```
    public static int[] invierteArreglo(int a[]){
          int resultado[] = new int[a.length];

          for(int elemento: a){
                resultado[indice] = a;
                indice = indice - 1;
                }
          return resultado;
   }
```

Alguien que sea tan amable de ayudarme por favor, no e podidio solucionarlo.

Comment: Si no nos dices en que te ayudamos no podremos hacerlo. Por cierto ya te mencionaron que los arreglos se escriben `tipo[] arreglo` y no `tipo arreglo[]`. Fíjate en el parámetro.

Comment: ¿Dónde está declarado `índice`?

Comment: @Mateo java acepta ambas notaciones.

Comment: Ya pero está obsoleto. En algún momento puede dejar de funcionar así que mejor acostumbrarse bien.

Comment: le agregue la variable índice que inicia en 0, int índice =0; pero en la linea de resultado[indice]=a; me marca error

Comment: @Mateo los arreglos se pueden declarar de las 2 formas `int[] a y int a[]` son validas en java.

Comment: ¿Y qué mensaje de error estás obteniendo en esa línea? Quizás tiene que ver con que estás intentando asignarle a un número entero un arreglo. Es decir tienes que asignar a un elemento de resultado, un elemento de a, y no a completo: `resultado[indice] = a[loquesea];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para invertir un arreglo debes hacer uso de los indices del arreglo que das como parámetro

ejemplo

```
int [] numeros={1,3,2,4,5,6}; es un array de 6 elementos con sus indices 0,1,2,3,4,5
```

al querer invertir deberás recorrer el array comenzando de su ultimo indice hasta el primero,por ende tu indice seria

```
indice = a.length-1; //6-1
```

observacion:

- tal como te lo mencionan un array se puedes declarar de la siguiente manera

  `int[] a o int a[]`
- si `a` es un array dado como parametro no puedes meterlo dentro de otro
  array,a menos que sea un array de array pero resultado es un array de tipo  `int`

  `resultado[indice] = a;`

tu código quedaría así:

```
public static int[] invierteArreglo(int a []  ){
          int resultado[] = new int[a.length];
          int indice=a.length-1;

          for(int elemento: a){
                resultado[indice] = elemento;
                indice = indice - 1;
                }
          return resultado;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo mi solución como alternativa a lo que ya tienes hecho:

```
public static int[] InvierteArreglo(int[] a)
{
   int[] resultado = new int[a.length];

   for(int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      resultado[a.length - 1 - i] = a[i];
   }

   return resultado;
}
```

Se recorre el **arreglo a** desde la última posición hasta la primera, es decir de derecha a izquierda y cada elemento del **arreglo a** se irá guardando de izquierda a derecha en el **arreglo resultado**. Por último se retorna el **arreglo resultado** con los elementos ya invertidos.

Answer (score 0):

En el método de tipo arreglo entero no se está haciendo una invertida de elementos se puede notar como en el for índice no esta definido, solo se le asigna ese valor menos 1 la verdad no se está haciendo lo que debería de hacer el método. Lo correcto es usar los índices para poder invertir el arreglo que se recibe como parámetro.
Accediendo al indice con

```
indice = a.lenght-1 //Lo cual es limite a 1
```

El código del método estaría quedando así

```
public static int[] invierteArreglo(int a []  ){
      int invertido[] = new int[a.length];
      int indice=a.length-1;

      for(int i: a){
            invertido[indice] = i;
            indice = indice - 1;
            }
      return invertido;
```

}

El método retornará los elementos del array ya invertidos

Para llamarlo solo defines un array, por ejemplo.

```
int array[] = {3,4,5,6,7,7};
```

Recuerda que el array empieza desde cero son 6 posiciones lo cual es 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Lo llamas así

```
invierteArreglo(array);
```

La salida debería verse así

```
7,7,6,5,4,3
```

Listo con esto ya funciona tu método.